# Conditional UpdateTargetId in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to update my target according to condition in asp.net mvc frame work,
My code is

```
<div>
 <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
 <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitPress", new { id = Model.UserID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "DivAddEditUser" }))
       {%>
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
               <input type="submit" name="save" id="btnSave" value="Save" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<% } %>
</div>
```

Now my question is if validation is false on submit view I want to update div-"DivAddEditUser"  and is validation is true so data will insert in database and it should update other div-"ViewData".

So how this possible please help me to come out

Answer (score 0):

Create a code block in your view and assign your conditional variable there. You can then assign `UpdateTargetId = variable`. Because we don't need to make the variable accessible from outside of render blocks, we can use either the   or `<%`...`%>`

```
<% String myVariable = null;
if(validation == false)
{myVariable = "DivAddEditUser";}
else
{myVariable = "ViewData";} %>

<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitPress", new { id = Model.UserID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = myVariable }))
```

I've just used this technique with the Razor view engine and believe it should work the same way in ASP. Please let me know if it does/doesn't work out.

Thanks,
Jon